# Getting desired key name

Tags: php, memcached

My code is:

```
 $key1='qwerty199@234.45';
 $key2='qwerty199@234.45';
 $key3='qwerty199@234.45';

 $item=array(
'$key1' => 'casfid=qwert12345',
'$key2' => '2=1234567890',
'$key3' => 'product name=test ivr'
);

$static_client->setMulti($item,time() + 300);

$null = null;
$keys = array_keys($item);
$got = $static_client->getMulti($keys, $null, Memcached::GET_PRESERVE_ORDER);

foreach ($got as $k => $v) {
echo "$k $v\n";
```

However, output is :

```
$key1 casfid=qwert12345
$key2 2=1234567890
$key3 product name=test ivr
```

Is there any way through which I can get desired values of '$key1','$key2','$key3' defined above.

Thanks

Comment: why is `$key1`, `$key2` and `$key3` is the same? It will overwrite each other.

Comment: Values of $key1,$key2,$key3 can be same or different

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks from the key variables when defining the array, instead of doing this:

```
$item=array(
    '$key1' => 'casfid=qwert12345',
    '$key2' => '2=1234567890',
    '$key3' => 'product name=test ivr'
);
```

Do this:

```
$item=array(
    $key1 => 'casfid=qwert12345',
    $key2 => '2=1234567890',
    $key3 => 'product name=test ivr'
);
```

**Edit:**
To allow multiple values on each key, each key will have to contain an array:

```
$item = array();
$item[$key1][] = 'casfid=qwert12345';
$item[$key2][] = '2=1234567890';
$item[$key3][] = 'product name=test ivr';
```

I'll leave it up to you to discover the correct way to read from this or add more data.

Comment: Now getting following :

    qwerty199@234.45 product name=test ivr

casfid=qwert12345 and 2=1234567890 is missing. If values of $key1,$key2,$key3 are same, then how can I get other two values.

Sorry for language, I am new in php and memcache
Thanks

Comment: That means the key is correct but since you're using the same value in all $key variables they are overwriting the previous ones. Each key in an array can only hold one value.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in php. IF values of $key1,$key2,$key3 is same, then how can I get the desired reuslt.
Thanks

Comment: I think you need to explain a little more what you're trying to achieve, with your current solution you will not be able to get the other values if all have the same key. For example, is the key important?

Comment: My requirement is using a kev value pair such that value of $key could be any string. For that particular  key, there wll be multiple values . Output could be :

    qwerty199@234.45  casfid=qwert12345
    qwerty199@234.45  2=1234567890
    qwerty199@234.45  product name=test ivr

or
    qwerty199@234.45 casfid=qwert12345
                 2=1234567890
                 product name=test ivr
Thanks

Comment: In that case you need to have multi-dimensional arrays, each key should contain an array of values.